# How can I know which Email Alert is sent in a visual flow action?

Tags: visual-workflow

So I have a visual flow that sends an email alert.
Is there a way, after I wrote the flow, to know which email alert is sent?
If I only click on the 'Action' item, it doesn't give me this information:
[image]

And when I click it:
[image]

There is no indication of the email alert used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually in the title/header of the pop up when you click edit on the element.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could look at the metadata to figure it out if you were in your source control/IDE. Specifically, [FlowActionCall](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm#FlowActionCall) which contains `ActionName` which will have your email alert name (with object name prefixed)

```xml
<actionCalls>
    <name>Testing_Flow_Email_Alert_Name</name>
    <label>Testing Flow Email Alert Name</label>
    <locationX>197</locationX>
    <locationY>247</locationY>
    <actionName>Account.Kris_Email_Alert</actionName> <!-- the email alert -->
    <actionType>emailAlert</actionType>
    ...
</actionCalls>
```

Comment: Flow XML - a real joy to inspect :-)

Comment: jee, thanks. Have no clue how I missed it.